# SQL-Server - Ability to pass subset parameter in the select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying create a query that will output a total number, as well as a subset of the total number in `SQL-Server`.  I can think of a way to do this via subqueries, but that seems like a ton of work.  Is there a faster way to write this query?

```
Table name: orders


OrderID    Date           Type           OrderSize
1          1/1/2012       Electronics    $282.02
2          1/1/2012       Electronics    $1,000.56
3          1/1/2012       Books          $17.25
4          1/1/2012       Books          $10.00
```

What I am trying to output would look like this:

```
Date       ElectronicOrders    ElectronicOrderSize    BookOrders   BookOrderSize
1/1/2012   2                   $1,282.58              2            $27.25
```

I could create a temp table, then run 2 update queries - 1 `WHERE Type = 'Electronics'` and 1 `WHERE Type = 'Books'`.

What I have seen in some programming languages, such as `R`, is the ability to subset a variable.  Is there a way for me to say something like:

```
count(OrderID, Type = 'Electronics) as ElectronicOrders, sum(OrderSize, Type = 'Electronics') as ElectronicOrderSize
```

Or am I stuck with `subqueries` and `UPDATE queries`?

Comment: This looks like a PIVOT but it is important to know whether you know all of the potential categories or not.

Comment: I do know all the categories...  I'm not familiar with `PIVOT`...  searching now.

Comment: Pivot would work, I think.  I can see how to do 1 calculation, such as count(*), but not count(*) and sum(*) at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't ever gotten the new PIVOT syntax to make sense in my head but you can do a pivot table by grouping, and taking aggregate functions in a case statement.

```
select [date], sum( case when type = 'Electronics' then (ordersize) else 0 end) AS ElectronicsSum,
sum( case when type = 'Electronics' then 1 else 0 end) AS ElectronicsCount,
sum( case when type = 'Books' then (ordersize) else 0 end) AS BooksSum,
sum( case when type = 'Books' then 1 else 0 end) AS BooksCoumt
from orders
group by [date]
```

I put a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=2/1db0e/1#!3/d99aa/7) thing up to test it out.  If Aaron B. posts up a solution, give him the answer credit, I might not have even recognized the pivotyness of it.

Comment: +1 this is probably what I would have done. There is likely a more elegant way with PIVOT (maybe two PIVOTS?) but I haven't mastered the syntax yet either.

Comment: This worked exactly the way I needed it to.  Thanks for the help.